# How can I make squid log full request and full responses

Tags: logging, squid

Is there a configuration parameter to do this? 
Tried a google search, but only solution I found required me to recompile the squid source.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

The [logformat directive](http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/logformat/) controls the log format.  At a glance, most header information is available.  If you need something that's not in the list of available information, then yes, you'll have to patch the code.